# Typo3 missing all the styles(css/js) after upgraded from 6.2.X to the 7.6.10

Tags: styles, typo3

I just upgraded the Typo3 from 6.2.26 to 7.6.10, but the styles at the front page are all missing. Just the content and data from the DB shown on it. I guess maybe it was the loss of.

[image]

So, if there somebody met this question too, share your ideas with me. Looking for your advice, many thanks.

Comment: Is your upgraded website accessible online? If so, please provide an URL which makes some analysis easier. Thx

Comment: Really sorry that this website is just a beta and i don't have this right to put it online.I couldn't find any css/js temp files at /typo3temp like what it should  be in 6.2.26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check if your JS/CSS files are present in the source code of your page. If they are, there are two possibilities, imo:

1. your html is cached but the cache files were deleted/moved. Solution: clean your cache (the best is to clean it from the install tool -> "Important actions")
2. Your baseURL/absRefPrefix is broken. I would advice to use `config.absRefPrefix` instead of `baseURL` (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html)

Comment: Thank you for you advice, i'm ready to upgrade it again,and hope it will be all right this time.