# TYPO3 miss all the styles and there are no js/css file under the temp dir

Tags: typo3

Still the problem of TYPO3's style. Well, i find there are no css/js files under the temp dir. And i tried to copy the js file to there, but no effect.Is there anyone who met this problem before? Plz some advice, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please be more precise about your setup. Applying basic formatting rules of the english language further helps to motivate others to read your words.

Comment: Can you enhance the description of your problem: what files do you expect (place and task of file)? also state which version of TYPO3 (tag) and extensions involved you use. we also might need your typoscript configuration. please provide more information!

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126381/typo3-missing-all-the-stylescss-js-after-upgraded-from-6-2-x-to-the-7-6-10

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Things I would suggest is:

- Have you added css_styled_content and/or fluid_styled_content in the Typoscript template of your website? (In the *Contains* Tab)
- Have you added the CSS files in the config part of your template

  ```
  page = PAGE
  page {   
    includeCSS {
      cssFile = path/to/css/style.css
    }
  }
  ```
- Check if the path to the file is correct in your template.

Since you are looking for files in the Temp folder, are you having problems with file gzip compression?

```
config {    
  concatenateCss = 1
  compressCss = 1
}
```

- Check [here](https://checkgzipcompression.com/) if GZip compression is enabled, if not ask your webhost if it's possible, and how to enable. This might need a few lines in your HTACESS file to activate.